# Wrong behaviour in Google Chrome Object.defineProperty?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, defineproperty

I am trying to create an object with setters and getters, and this is my code:

```
var Player = function(height){
    var _height = height;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'height', {
      enumerable: false
    , configurable: true
    , writable: false
    , get: function(){return _height;}
    , set: function(val){_height = val;}
    });
}
```

var myPlayer = new Player(10);

Even though the `writable` property of the defineProperty options is set to false, I get the following error:

`Invalid property.  A property cannot both have accessors and be writable or have a value, #<Object>`

The same is happening when the `writable` is set to true of course, but the error disappears if I remove the `writable` line.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? This is happening on Google Chrome, Version 30.0.1599.66

Comment: Error seems descriptive... Why would you have a getter and setter for a non-writable property?

Comment: The error is getting displayed in both cases, `writable: true` and `writable: false`. Isn't this weird?

Comment: You can only either have the attributes `writable` and `value` or `get` and `set`, not any mixture of them. Since you specify `writable` , you cannot use `get` or `set`. See [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Oh, it makes sense then. This comment should be an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for `Object.defineProperty` clarifies this:

> Property descriptors present in objects come in two main flavors: data descriptors and accessor descriptors. A data descriptor is a property that has a value, which may or may not be writable. An accessor descriptor is a property described by a getter-setter pair of functions. A descriptor must be one of these two flavors; it cannot be both.

This means, that you can use either one of those:

- `writable` and `value`
- `get` and `set`

But you cannot use any combination of them. In your example, you specify the `writable` attribute, which means that it is a data descriptor, which disallows `get` and `set` attributes.