# Set method in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writting a small library in node and i have found some interesting behaviors. When i try these code on cmd:

```
Object.prototype.set = function (a) { this.a = a };
let obj = {};
obj.set(6);
obj
```

It returns: `{ a: [Setter] }`

I try to type `obj.a` and then it returns correctly `6`. When i check it on browser it still runs normally without any problem:

```
Object.prototype.set = function (a) { this.a = a };
let obj = {};
obj.set(6);
obj
// => { a: 6 }
```

So i wonder what has happened with node. Is this some kind of side effect? Should i care about it and should i put these code into my library? Thanks!

P/s: I'm using node version 7.7.3

Comment: Setter could be something like a Generator / Iterator, due to which as soon as it is accessed, it returns a value? This might be something introduced in ES6 and I'm waiting for an answer too.

Comment: You may want to note that it's generally considered an anti-pattern to add non-standard methods to built-in object prototypes.  Besides the opportunity for conflict with other add-on libraries, it can mess up other code that gets confused when enumerable things show up in places they aren't supposed to be.  For example, a simple `for (x in obj)` loop will now show the `set` property.

Comment: I don't worry about that, i use `Object.defineProperty` and use it only for `Object.prototype`. it is predictable (at least when someone use my lib). i'm just wondering whether this is a bad behavior and it may lead to other serious problems! :/

Comment: Oh, i've just checked. `Object.defineProperty` cannot define `set` property because there is `value` inside `descriptor`! [Wrong behavior in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349309/wrong-behaviour-in-google-chrome-object-defineproperty)